# Python: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long when saving plot as image

Tags: python, matplotlib, raspberry-pi

I'm programming using python on a raspberry PI 1. I get this error when I try to save a plot using plt.savefig, even if the content of the plot is a single value. I have a Tkinter running on a main prosess, I have seperate thread doing some calculations by calling functions in a different .py file, the plt.savefig is in one of these functions. plt.savefig works fine when calling the second .py file directly, so I guess this has something to do with my threading? My knowledge is kind of limited, I would really appreciate some help :(

Edit:

```
import threading
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def saveplot():
    plt.plot(3)
    plt.savefig("plot.jpg")
    time.sleep(10)

threads = []
t = threading.Thread(target=saveplot)
threads.append(t)
t.start()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "Slett.py", line 6, in saveplot
    plt.savefig("plot.jpg")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 578, in savefig
    draw()   # need this if 'transparent=True' to reset colors
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 571, in draw
    get_current_fig_manager().canvas.draw()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 350, in draw
    tkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, colormode=2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 21, in blit
    _tkagg.tkinit(tk.interpaddr(), 1)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Comment: The single number you are trying to save is too big.  C longs only go up to 2^63 - 1, but your number is bigger than that.  Or, your number is negative and smaller than -(2^63).

Comment: @Kevin I think `2^63-1` is only on 64 bit systems, I believe the maximum is `sys.maxsize` regardless of platform.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: That's for `ssize_t`, which is usually but not always the same as `long` (Windows is a good counterexample; it has 32-bit longs and 64-bit pointers).

Comment: (what the heck?) anyway, @user2603003, could you post some code that can reproduce this behaviour? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: FWIW your code [raises `RuntimeError`](http://pastebin.com/rZUUinaV) in my desktop computer using the tkagg backend but the figure is saved. It works flawlessly with the agg backend though.

Comment: Yeah, the figure is saved on my system as well, but it would be nice to not have the program halted. Not sure what a agg backend is though?

Answer (score 0):

please look at the thread: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7680 this is bug in matplotlib https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/7634